# Flex 4.7 TabbedViewNavigator fixed tab width and no shrinking

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.7

I have a TabbedViewNavigator which has a high number of views. I don't want the tabs on the bottom of my app to shrink. Instead, I would like that a horizontal Scroll bar appears and some kind of indication that there is more content to the right or left.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: There is no Flex SDK 4.7.  The last Adobe release was 4.6 and the first Apache release was 4.8.

Comment: I have Flash Builder 4.7. In my Adobe sdks folder I have the folder 4.7.0 which my compiler is using. It also says on the compiler Flex 4.7.0. I don't know maybe you are right. And why does the tab flex4.7 exist in Stackoverflow then?

Comment: I am often wrong; but this time I do not believe that is the case.  I have Flash Builder 4.7 too. The SDKs that ship with it are 3.6.0 and 4.6.0.  The latest download from Adobe is 4.6.0 http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html The first tag for Apache Flex is 4.8 https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-sdk/repo?p=flex-sdk.git;a=summary .  I have no idea where you got a Flex 4.7.0; but please share.

Comment: I think you are right I downloaded the Air SDK and I must have created a new folder called 4.7.0 where I installed the new Air SDK 3.7 for Apple Mobile apps dev. Don't remember... So but that would mean that the flag Flex4.7 is supposed to incorporate questions for Flash Builder 4.7.

Comment: A lot of people get confused between Flash Builder and Flex; so someone probably created the tag in error.  There are only a handful of questions on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following link can help you out

http://flexponential.com/2011/10/23/enable-scrolling-in-the-tab-bar-of-a-tabbedviewnavigator/

Comment: Thanks altough there is nothing there to indicate content on the right and left of my TabBar